# How to display aggregated value from a custom object into summary roll up field

Tags: roll-up-summary

I have created a Junction-Object between **Opportunity** and a `Custom Object` we use.

On each of the `custom objects`, there is a drop-down field of `fulfillment`.

On **Opportunity**, I need to know, how many of the `custom objects` of that **Opportunity** have reached fulfillment on a certain date.

I created a roll-up summary on **Opportunity** to count the number of custom objects, but I can't filter by the fulfillment value.

I would like to show, for example: if 4 out of 5 objects are fulfilled - to display 80%, etc..

A datefield I added is: Fulfillment-Date - that is set when a custom-object has reached fulfillment

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished with a formula field and 2 roll-up summaries:

1. Roll-up summary which counts the total count() of the `custom objects`
2. Roll-up summary which counts the count() of the `custom objects` which are fulfilled
3. Formula field which divides #2 by #1 and outputs a percent value.